# ¿Aplicaciones de arreglos unidimensionales y multidimensionales?

Tags: java

¿Cuáles son las aplicaciones en java de los arreglos unidimensionales y multidimensionales? Si pudieran citar codigos para entender este tema seria perfecto.

Comment: Hola tu pregunta es algo ambigua, si buscas en google arreglos en java seguro te saldran mucha informacion, recuerda que stackoverflow es para hacer preguntas en concreto y no sobre tutoriales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La aplicación más usual de los **arreglos unidimensionales** es para guardar un conjunto de datos de forma consecutiva, por ejemplo requieres guardar los nombres de varias personas.

```
String nombres[]={"Julia", "José", "Manuel", "Brenda"};
```

Con el arreglo si quieres encontrar un nombre basta con recorrer  arreglo hasta encontrarlo, de otra forma usarías una variable para cada nombre algo que no sirve si tienes una cantidad n muy grande de nombres que debes guardar.

Otras aplicaciones de los arreglos son para hacer estructuras de datos  tales cómo.

- Pilas
- Colas
- Listas

---

En el caso de  **arreglo Multidimensional**, lo más común es usar **matrices**, las cuales pueden ocuparse para hacer operaciones con matrices en términos matemáticos:

- Suma de matrices
- Resta de matrices
- Multiplicación de matrices
- Determinante de una matriz
- Resolución de sistemas de ecuaciones